# Assignment for school and having multiple issues with lists

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x

I'm currently taking a python course and am really have issues with lists. I am trying to make this program in the most 'efficient' way possible (using least lines and processing power).

So far I have:

```
import os
import functools
file = input("Input file name(.txt):   ")

lstData=[]
if(os.path.isfile(file)):
    weather = open(file, 'r')
    for line in weather:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(",")

        for i in range(len(line)):
            if(line[i].isdigit()):
                line[i] = int(line[i])
        lstData.append(line)
Jan = ((lstData[0][1:]))

    F=c*1.8+32
    return(F)
def average(values):
    length=len(values)
    total_sum=0

    for i in range(length):
        total_sum+=sum(values)
    total_sum =sum(values)
    average= float(total_sum/length)
```

Here are the rules for this project:

> I have generated an arbitrary number of temperature readings in degrees centigrade and stored these in a file called “weather.txt”. Complete the following:
>
> - Create a function to load the sample weather data, stored in file “weather.txt”, into an appropriate data structure – the numerical data should be converted to an appropriate data type, and these values returned to the calling function.
> - Create a function to determine the average for this list of values (the temperature data in this case).
> - Create a function that will convert a temperature from centigrade to Fahrenheit. 
>     Create two function that can located the highest and lowest temperature in a range of value.
> - Using the functions developed above, create a program to complete the following:
>
>   - Create a simple menu system to complete the following:
>   - Prompt for a file to load
>   - If the file exists then load the data into a list object
>   - If the file does not exist, prompt the user to enter a real file name
>   - Display the average temperature for all months in Centigrade and Fahrenheit
>   - Display the highest and lowest temperature for each month
>   - Exit
>
> DATA:
>
> ```
> Jan, -2,-5,-6,-10,2,1,6,-2,3,1,0,1
> Feb,-6,-11,-5,-4,-2,-1,0,2,5,3,5,4
> Mar,5,8,9,10,13,15,18,10,12,13,11
> Apr,15,17,19,15,16,18,19,15,17,14
> May,18,19,23,22,25,21,20,19,22,25
> June,25,28,27,29,30,35,33,32,31,34,33
> Jul,33,32,36,37,40,41,42,45,41,39,37,40
> Aug,40,41,421,43,39,45,43,39,39,40,41,42
> Sep,38,37,36,33,35,29,28,29,25,23,26,27,30
> Oct,27,24,24,20,22,19,18,20,21,18,17,15,18,21
> Nov,16,19,14,15,12,15,11,10,9,10,6,11,8,7,5,3
> Dec,2,5,6,1,7,8,3,2,-1,0,2,-2,1,0,-2,-4,1,0,-2,-1,0
> ```

I'm not asking anyone to do it but if anyone has good knowledge of lists I would extremely appreciate it.

I would like to make functions that can take the string off the beginning of the list and then turn the rest of the string into a float or integer. I have not had any luck yet.

I also cannot use any of the given function or max, min, average, etc. and have to make my own. This isn't a real big problem. It's just my inability to work with lists. This will be in Python 3.3/3.4 if that makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not completely clear what about lists it is that you don't understand. Try to reduce the scope of the question, and formulate a more precise and short one. The purpose of this is twofold; (1) to make the question easier to answer and (2) to make you structure your thoughts better and maybe even figure it out on your own.

Comment: *"I am trying to make this program in the most 'efficient' way possible (using least lines and processing power)"* General rule of thumb: first get it working, then get it working better.

Comment: Btw, you should check out *list comprehension*, one of Python's greatest features.

Comment: @Henrik no the OP shouldn't.  If the asker needs help with using lists, adding list comprehension serves no purpose here.

Comment: @SimonT I disagree. List comprehension is probably the most common way of working with lists in Python, why not learn how from the get-go? The goal was also to use as few lines as possible, which surely has to be to promote usage of list comprehension.

Comment: @Henrik I do agree that list comprehension is a useful tool for understanding and writing good Python code, and it is often more efficient and concise than using `for` loops and `list.append`.  However, I see it as akin to teaching calculus to someone who needs to learn to find the optimal value of a quadratic function - the OP hasn't reached a (somewhat subjective) point where learning more advanced topics is the right choice.  Like @DesertIvy said, the OP needs to get it working first.

Answer (score 0):

You could read your data into a dictionary of lists like this:

```
def read_temps(filename):
  temps = {}
  f = open(filename, "r")
  line = f.readline()
  while line != "":
    a = line.split(",")
    temps[a[0].strip()] = [float(x) for x in a[1:]]
    line = f.readline()
  f.close()
  return temps

temps = read_temps("temps.txt")
print temps
```

Output:

```
{'Mar': [5.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 13.0, 15.0, 18.0, 10.0, 12.0, 13.0, 11.0],
 'Feb': [-6.0, -11.0, -5.0, -4.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.0, 5.0, 4.0],
 'Aug': [40.0, 41.0, 421.0, 43.0, 39.0, 45.0, 43.0, 39.0, 39.0, 40.0, 41.0, 42.0],
 'Sep': [38.0, 37.0, 36.0, 33.0, 35.0, 29.0, 28.0, 29.0, 25.0, 23.0, 26.0, 27.0, 30.0],
 'Apr': [15.0, 17.0, 19.0, 15.0, 16.0, 18.0, 19.0, 15.0, 17.0, 14.0],
 'June': [25.0, 28.0, 27.0, 29.0, 30.0, 35.0, 33.0, 32.0, 31.0, 34.0, 33.0],
 'Jul': [33.0, 32.0, 36.0, 37.0, 40.0, 41.0, 42.0, 45.0, 41.0, 39.0, 37.0, 40.0],
 'Jan': [-2.0, -5.0, -6.0, -10.0, 2.0, 1.0, 6.0, -2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
 'May': [18.0, 19.0, 23.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 20.0, 19.0, 22.0, 25.0],
 'Nov': [16.0, 19.0, 14.0, 15.0,12.0, 15.0, 11.0, 10.0, 9.0, 10.0, 6.0, 11.0, 8.0, 7.0, 5.0, 3.0],
 'Dec': [2.0, 5.0, 6.0, 1.0, 7.0, 8.0, 3.0, 2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 2.0, -2.0, 1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, 1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0],
 'Oct': [27.0, 24.0, 24.0, 20.0, 22.0, 19.0, 18.0, 20.0, 21.0, 18.0, 17.0, 15.0, 18.0, 21.0]}
```

Comment: "yes, but" a dictionary returns in arbitrary (essentially random) order.

Answer (score 0):

```
# assumes Python 3.x
import os

def get_filename(prompt):
    while True:
        fname = input(prompt)
        if os.path.isfile(fname):
            return fname

def load_weather(fname):
    weather = []
    with open(fname) as inf:
        for line in inf:
            month, temps = line.split(",", 1)
            temps = [float(temp) for temp in temps.rstrip().split(",")]
            weather.append((month, temps))
    return weather

def f_to_c(f):
    return (f - 32.) / 1.8

def c_to_f(c):
    return c * 1.8 + 32.

def average(lst):
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

def main():
    fname = get_filename("Enter the name of your weather data file: ")
    weather = load_weather(fname)

    print("Month    Low   Avg  High")
    for month,temps in weather:
        print("{:<5} {:>5.1f} {:>5.1f} {:>5.1f}".format(month, min(temps), average(temps), max(temps)))

if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```